# React native Changing default screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this link in my gmail, **http://localhost:5000/{{changepassword}}** that if the user clicsk the link it will go to changepassword screen, my problem is the link always go to the login page.

***note:both login and changing password doesnt required token, the only difference is the url link***

//app.js

```
<QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
  <SafeAreaProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="SplashScreen">
          <Stack.Screen
            name="SplashScreen"
            component={SplashScreen}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Login"
            component={Login}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Changepassword"
            component={Changepassword}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  </SafeAreaProvider>
  </QueryClientProvider>
```

//splashscreen

```
navigation.replace(token === null ? 'Login' : 'Homepage')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the token value null that's why it goes to the login screen. First check token value in splash screen

Comment: yes, but changing password doesnt required token too

Comment: both login and changing password doesnt required token,
the only difference is the url link